# best python lib to make the textarea safe in the web page when user submit

Tags: python, textarea, tags

i want to clean some tag like : `<script>` and other,

so what python lib you are  using to do this .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

This function should work for you:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1655/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Web2py , it is a webframework for python with support for Wiki Markup , MarkDown , and many things + Server side Validation , XSS Prevention. If you want to use only it's Lib you can use gluon of web2py (which is lib of web2py framework)

www.web2py.com